# Reverse generic relations and Generic Relations - Database design improvement

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In a simple scenario, where I have many `measurements` table that describe the measurements that comes from a specific protocol and every measurement is linked to the respective parent device, I was looking for an optimization of my database, putting all the measurements into a table and reference from this table the respective device.

Now, keeping in mind that this table is heavily used in read/write and especially in filtering operations, I was looking for a smarter solution...I've found the Django Generic Relations and Reverse Relations, but this approach it doesn't convince me at all because, as now, with a simple select with a where the problem is solved, but using a generic relation, the ORM will generate a lot of inner joins (if I'm not wrong) and this is an aspect that I would want to avoid.

So, anyone with smarter idea?

My goal is to remove tons of `if` in my code that at this time are used to decide what table it will be queried based on the protocol type, as shown below:

```
#MODBUS
if smartdevice_device_parent == 'smart_device_modbus':
    ...Select from the right table and serialize the data...

#RS485
elif smartdevice_device_parent == 'smart_device_rs485':
    ...Select from the right table and serialize the data...

#OPC
elif smartdevice_device_parent == 'smart_device_opc':
    ...Select from the right table and serialize the data...

#MQTT
elif smartdevice_device_parent == 'smart_device_mqtt':
    ...Select from the right table and serialize the data...
else:
    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'message': (_(ERROR)),
                         'data': ''})
```

Comment: So every parent device has its own table?

Comment: Yes, a table for every parent that inherits from the master abstract model definition.

Comment: Any news @CoffeeBasedLifeform

Comment: Could you post the models, so I can get a better idea of the structure?